# Help me rephrase: 相比看到子女长大成家，没有其他可以更让他们感觉放心的了

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, writing-critique

Reading the sentence below out loud felt extremely awkward, however I can't figure which part is improperly constructed to begin fixing the sentence.

> 相比看到子女长大成家，没有其他可以更让他们感觉放心的了。

I want to express the following idea (in English):

> To [Chinese parents], there's no any other thing that's more settling than to see their children grow up and form families.

Comment: 对中国父母来说，没有什么事比看到子女们长大成家更让人安心的了。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider: 沒有比兒女長大成家，更讓父母安心。

have fun :)

Comment: Aww some of the things are lost here from the intended idea. But I think I know where the fault point is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the chinese language is "fuzzy", it you list everything in details, the sentence would be awkward; that's why my suggestion missed some of your intended idea.

Comment: @ 水巷孑蠻,  I don't think  this is sentence is correct.

Comment: it's not a sentence :)

水巷 is, well, you need to decipher; hints: it's the second character of a city.

蠻, is barbarian of the south :)

孑, ok, this character, let me ask you now, what do you perceive?

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese like to use phrases, and in fact, many sentences in Chinese are formed by a sequence of phrases to give you the meaning without considering much about the stuff like "is, are, have, has" in English.

Thus, **the proper use of phrases are very important**.

In your sentence, there is no a conventional saying "长大成家", which make the whole sentence sound strange.

In the original English sentence, there are two phrases:"grow up and form families", and I would recommend translating them separately to "长大成人和成家立业".

Hope it helps you :)